# Trying to retrieve videoid's from channel on YouTube Data API and their comments

Tags: python-3.x, list, youtube-data-api

I am trying take the list of videoids and extract the comments from those ids in a list. I am having trouble figuring out a way to loop through all of the videoids (I have been able to get one video, but it stops there)

Currently, I get an error saying that it can't find the videoId (it is not being passed)

```
import os
import googleapiclient.discovery
import sys
import csv
import re
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

api_service_name = "youtube"
api_version = "v3"
DEVELOPER_KEY = "CENSORED"
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
api_service_name, api_version, developerKey = DEVELOPER_KEY)

#Calculating timestamp for 2 weeks before this script is run

now = datetime.now()

weeks_calculated = now + timedelta(weeks=-2)

#Passing parameters to API to retrieve video ids for the past 2 weeks

def get_id(youtube,channelId):
    response = youtube.search().list(
                part="snippet",
                type='video',
                channelId=channelId,
                publishedAfter='{}'.format(weeks_calculated.isoformat("T") + "Z")
                #ublishedAfter="2021-08-10T00:00:00Z"
                #rder="time",
                #pageToken=pageToken
                #maxResults=maxResults 
    ).execute()
                
    return response

#Passing parameters to API to retrieve comments by video id

def get_comments(youtube,videoId):
    response = youtube.commentThreads().list(
                part="snippet,replies",
                videoId=videoId,
                order="time",
                #pageToken=pageToken,
                textFormat="plainText",
                moderationStatus="published",
                #maxResults=maxResults 
    ).execute()
    
    return response


comment_text = []
video_id = []
    
def get_channel_data():
    channels = [{"id":"UCQlVOYJyQp64rA12ac0mv6g"}]   
    for channel in channels:
        video_data = get_id(youtube,channel['id'])
        for i in video_data['items']:
            videoData = i['id']['videoId']
            video_id.append(videoData)
    
    return video_id



        
def get_comment_data():
    
    videoId = get_channel_data()
    
    videoId = videoId
    
    response = youtube.commentThreads().list(
        part="snippet,replies",
        videoId=videoId,
        order="time",
        textFormat="plainText",
        moderationStatus="published"
        #maxResults=maxResults 
        ).execute()
    
    while response:
    
        for videoId[0] in response:
        
            for item in response['items']:
                original = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal']
                comment_text.append(original)
            
    return comment_text
            
    

    
get_comment_data()
```

Comment: You need to pass the request parameter `type='video'` to your invocation of the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint; that's because, by default, this endpoint returns several kind of resources other than video resources.

Comment: On the other hand, please be kind to post *cleaned off* source code such that your fellow SO users don't have to read pointless (meaningless) code (like, for example, `for _ in range(1)`).

Comment: @stvar noted, thanks for the tips. I have added the type='video'. Now, my question is- how do I use by videoId list to feed into my get_comments() function in a loop?